# AngularJS external UI library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm trying to make some animations with the components. I use Angular and Masonry (UI library). When I try to animate an element that is outside the ng-view it work's but when I try this on element inside the ng-view it doesn't work. I know that is due to jQuery - it runs the code once (when the page is loaded, but jQuery doesn't wait the ng-view element). How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your animation with directives on "Angular territory".

Check [angular-masonry](https://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/)

Comment: It can be possible. Try to init method you need in Masonry in controller